# Sending Email Notifications Immediately/On-Demand Versus Sending them Via Scheduler/Cron

Tags: c#, php, email, cron, scheduled-tasks

In your opinion (hopefully one that is formed based on fact, as opposed to emotion) what is the better way to send out email notifications from a website?

For example, say User A on your site requests a friendship with User B, at which point you would generate an email to send to User B.

The question is - when is the best time to send the email? Immediately, as part of the same execution path, or scheduling the email as part of a batch?

Like I said, my question is rather generalized, so you can assume different architectures - one server dedicated to hosting, another dedicated to emailing, a single server, cloud hosting, etc... I'm curious about all answers, really.

As I see it:

With immediate emails, you get timely emails, but you can potentially bog down your server by sending too many emails should your website receive a lot of traffic. That being said, because you're not sending a batch of emails, they are all one-offs.

If you batch your emails and have a scheduled task or cron job pick them up and send them, your emails are not as immediate - so assume you decrease the interval so that batches are sent every 1 minute. The issue, as I see it is concurrency - if another batch kicks off before the first one completes, you could risk sending double emails if you don't appropriately flag or lock what you're sending.

In my personal experience, when I've had emails sent off immediately on a high traffic site, performance wasn't impacted too much, though a number of emails failed to send out.

Thoughts?

Comment: `...this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.` - having said that, cron/batch processing is the way to do this IMHO, simply because it is more efficient from a HTTP perspective - the request the initiates the email does not have to wait for the email to be sent before it finishes and completes it's response. You can also easily implement things like merging messages if there are two messages in the queue destined for the same email address.

Answer (score 1):

I would say definitely *schedule* them. There has to be a tollerance in terms of user request and server action on it, as if someone is able to make someone other a friend, it also (I hope) is able to refuse a friendship with the same person. If so, what if I make fast accept and refuse clicks on your website.  ?

You have 2 options in this case, imo:

- like a SO does, add some timing on user clicks (you can not accept and refuse in 2 seconds)
- or you *can*, but at this point final message to the person whom friendship was accepted/requested is scheduled on the server and will send, say, after 30 minutes (or less, matter of architect choice)

Hope this helps.